Ubuntu 22.04 receives an IPv6 address under the same Wi-Fi router but is unable to access IPv6 websites, while Windows 10 behaves correctly
In my office network, I have a TP-LINK wifi router. All the ipv4 network works quite well. In the setting of the ipv6 in the wifi router, it is set as the "bridged" or "pass through" mode(see the document here: How to set up an IPv6 Internet connection on the TP-Link Wi-Fi Routers).
Under Windows 10, ipv6 works OK, I got the correct ipv6 address(I got two ipv6 address, one is started with 2001:xxxxxxx, which I think is the global ipv6 address, and another one is start with the fe80, and is the local link address. It can access the ipv6 websites correctly.
Under Ubuntu 22.04, I see it also got two ipv6 address similar with Windows 10, but I can't access any ipv6 websites, I also can't ping any ipv6 sites.
I just tested the android device, and badly, it has the same issue like the Ubuntu 22.04.
I believe the ipv6 address is assigned by the upper level gateway server, so under ubuntu, I got such "ifconfig" result:
wlxcdddddddddd: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.87.104  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.87.255
        inet6 2001:ddd:dddd:d::d:dddd  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::9b9f:7ce6:bd5c:d445  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether c8:dd:dd:dd:dd:dd  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2019255  bytes 787493044 (787.4 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2967086  bytes 1884873281 (1.8 GB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

Note I have change the hex value of the inet6 address to some "dddddd" like chars for security reasons.
Here is my route result:
::1 dev lo proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
2001:ddd:dddd:d::d:dddd dev wlxcdddddddd proto kernel metric 600 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev wlxcdddddddd proto kernel metric 1024 pref medium
default via fe80::42ee:ddff:fe60:1d9d dev wlxcdddddddd proto ra metric 20600 pref medium

It looks like the fe80::42ee:ddff:fe60:1d9d is the upper level gateway server, and the 2001:ddd:dddd:d::d:dddd is the assigned ipv6 address.
Any one know how to solve this issue?
Thanks.
BTW:
I have a similar question in the Ask Ubuntu site(see: networking - Under the same wifi router, ubuntu 22.04 got ipv6 address, but can't access ipv6 website, while windows 10 works correctly, why? - Ask Ubuntu), but I got no answers there, so I asked a similar question here in this site, I hope I could got some help here, thanks.
EDIT: Add my answer to u1686_grawity's comment:


Do all systems (both the working ones and non-working) have the
same default gateway? Your Ubuntu has fe80::42ee:ddff:fe60:1d9d; is
that the same as what Windows has?


Yes, under Windows 10, when I run the ipconfig /all command, I see the ipv6 gateway server is fe80::42ee:ddff:fe60:1d9d, so they are the same.


Does Android have any '2xxx:' IPv6 addresses at all? (Wi-Fi network
settings should list them.)


I'm currently not in the office, so I can't test Android device, I will update this information later.
EDIT2: I just tested an iphone device, it can get the 2xxx global ipv6 address, but it failed to access the ipv6 sites.


Are you using a USB Wi-Fi adapter?


Yes. I have tested with the wired connection to the wifi router(the wifi router has 4 wired LAN ports), the result is the same, I can't access ipv6 websites either under ubuntu.


Can you successfully ping fe80::42ee:ddff:fe60:1d9d%wlxcddd from
Ubuntu?


No, I can't. I can see that the wifi router's Local ipv6 Link address, which is fe80::82ea:7ff:febd:ee50, I can pint the wifi router's ipv6 address, but I can't pint the gateway server address, see the below "Edit 3" section.


Can you ping sites by their IP address (not domain name) from
Ubuntu, e.g. ping 2001:4860:4860::8888 or ping 2606:4700:4700::1111?


No, I can't. It looks like the ping package can't go through the wifi router in my Ubuntu. I can't ping the ipv6 dns server I see from the wifi network property dialog under ubuntu. But under Windows 10, I can pint many ipv6 sites successfully.
EDIT3: This is the result I try to ping the local wifi router.
ping6 -I wlxc83a35c042a2 fe80::82ea:7ff:febd:ee50
ping6: Warning: source address might be selected on device other than: wlxc83a35c042a2
PING fe80::82ea:7ff:febd:ee50(fe80::82ea:7ff:febd:ee50) from :: wlxc83a35c042a2: 56 data bytes
64 bytes from fe80::82ea:7ff:febd:ee50%wlxc83a35c042a2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=7.94 ms
64 bytes from fe80::82ea:7ff:febd:ee50%wlxc83a35c042a2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=1.81 ms
64 bytes from fe80::82ea:7ff:febd:ee50%wlxc83a35c042a2: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=1.44 ms

But I try to pint the gateway server, it just failed, see below:
ping6 -I wlxc83a35c042a2 fe80::42ee:ddff:fe60:1d9d
ping6: Warning: source address might be selected on device other than: wlxc83a35c042a2
PING fe80::42ee:ddff:fe60:1d9d(fe80::42ee:ddff:fe60:1d9d) from :: wlxc83a35c042a2: 56 data bytes
^C
--- fe80::42ee:ddff:fe60:1d9d ping statistics ---
13 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 12291ms



Do all systems (both the working ones and non-working) have the same default gateway? Your Ubuntu has fe80::42ee:ddff:fe60:1d9d; is that the same as what Windows has? 2) Does Android have any '2xxx:' IPv6 addresses at all? (Wi-Fi network settings should list them.) 3) Are you using a USB Wi-Fi adapter? 4) Can you successfully ping fe80::42ee:ddff:fe60:1d9d%wlxcddd from Ubuntu? 5) Can you ping sites by their IP address (not domain name) from Ubuntu, e.g. ping 2001:4860:4860::8888 or ping 2606:4700:4700::1111?


Hi, @u1686_grawity, many thanks for the help, I just updated my original question and I added all the answers to your comment questions, can you have a look? Thanks.

Out of curiosity what is the "upstream" of the TP-Link router? Is there another local router that handles multiple offices, or does it go directly to the ISP?

Hi, the "upstream" of my wifi TP-Link router is the "campus-wide network", I mean I don't know the whole structure, but it should have some toplevel routers and firewalls for our university.  The strange thing is that in my home, I use a OpenWRT router as the top level router, and after this OpenWRT router, there is a wifi TP-Link router, wihch has the same hardware/firmware version as the TP-Link wifi router in my office. In my home, ipv6 works correctly on any devices, but in my work office, I see only Windows 10 has ipv6 web access, not sure why.

What output did you get from the various ping-by-address attempts? When you tried to ping fe80::82ea:7ff:febd:ee50 (the local router), was that with the %wlxCDDDD included? (Specifying the interface is usually necessary when pinging link-local addresses.)

Hi, thanks. I just add the "Edit 3" section about the ping result, it looks like I can ping the local router, but I can't ping the gateway server. Also, in the "Edit 2", I have added a test of the iphone device result.
